# Are there any non-unit testing frameworks for visual studio or other?

Tags: automated-testing, integration-testing, end-to-end, test-tools

It seems SDETs or similar have to bend unit test frameworks to perform integration tests.  Test discovery in Xunit, Nunit, etc. intentionally discover tests in non-orderly ways and using TestPriority or Order decorators can get messy.

I want tests that inherit a state from a previous test (end-of-story, please don't philosophize why tests need to stand alone).

**If I have end-to-end 50 tests to make a "happy path" what is the best way to do that with today's tools?**  Lets say I am using c# with Webdriver and Xunit, but I would be interested in any stack.

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit, I'm a bit unclear on what you're trying to do. However, if you need to take a series of steps and see the result of those interactions, I would look at tools like [Fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org/) or [Specflow](http://specflow.org/). My gut feel is that Fitnesse is closer to what you want to accomplish though.

Answer (score 0):

For each of your tests the actual test is the last step.
Treat the other work as setup

I would organize as:

For test1 the test is step1
For test2 the test is step2 with 'before' setup step1
For test3 the test is step3 with 'before' setup step1, step2
For test4 the test is step4 with 'before' setup step1, step2, step3
...

Organizing this way would give various options for using iterators, extractions, etc. and using before and after actions available in most test frameworks.

Comment: Yes, that is how I am doing it.  And it makes sense for tests to run in parallel, etc.  It just feels painful as the test count gets deeper.